# Passing a templateParameter files to a bicep module

Tags: azure, powershell

I have this main bicep files here:

```
// Setting target scope
targetScope = 'subscription'

// Creating resource group
resource rg 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-01-01' = {
  name: 'rg-test1234'
  location: 'westus2'
}


// Deploying initial Bicep using modules
module initial './InitialDeployment_template.bicep' = {
  name: 'initialDeployment'
  scope: rg    // Deployed in the scope of resource group we created above
  params: {}
}
```

And the initial module needs this parameter file: `.\IniitiapDeployment_parameters.json`

I cannot find how to use parameter files to make this happen.   Even if I pass it as a TemplateParameterFile from Powershell, I cannot make it work

```
PS ~> New-AzSubscriptionDeployment `
>>   -Name demoSubDeployment `
>>   -TemplateFile Main.bicep `
>>   -TemplateParameterFile .\InitialDeployment_parameters.json -Location westus2 -WhatIf
```

Is this something possible?

Thanks

I have tried already to load the Json into a variables, but I cannot pass variables into params.

here is what I get with powershell TemplateParameterFile :

```
Error BCP035: The specified "object" declaration is missing the following required properties: "AutomationAccountName", "AzureADTenant", "AzureBastionSubnetAddressSpace", "BastionIPName"
```

Comment: What happens? Does the command throw an error? Does the deployment succeed but without the desire parameter data? "I cannot make it work" doesn't tell us anything, we can't see your screen :)

Comment: Sorry about that, here is what I get with powershell TemplateParameterFile : Error BCP035: The specified "object" declaration is missing the following required
properties: "AutomationAccountName", "AzureADTenant", "AzureBastionSubnetAddressSpace", "BastionIPName"

Comment: Please add those details [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76621564/edit)

Comment: Can you add what exactly is present in `InitialDeployment_template.bicep` file? @Ian Lafleur

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters in bicep files, create a `json` parameter file including all of the parameters being passed and their values. Once it is generated, use the `New-AzsubscriptionDeployment` command to deploy it.

For better understanding, I created a sample `module.bicep` for a resource group deployment and added the `parameters.json` file as shown below.

`module.parameters.json`

```bash
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"location": {
"value": "eastus"
     }
  }
}
```

`module.bicep`:

```bash
targetScope = 'subscription'
param  location  string
module  initial  './resourcegroup.bicep' = {
name: 'initialDeployment'
scope: subscription()
params: {
location: location
    }
}
```

`resourcegroup.bicep`:

```bash
targetScope = 'subscription'
param  location  string = 'eastus'
resource  resourceGroup  'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
name: 'newrg'
location: location
}
```

Having done all of the above steps, I deployed it by providing the template file as well as the template parameter file to the command below.

```
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -Name demoSubDeployment -TemplateFile module.bicep  -TemplateParameterFile "/home/lakshmi/module.parameters.json" -Location eastus
```

[image]

*Note:* Make sure to include all of the parameters from the main bicep file in the `params` block of module files.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-10.1.0) for more relevant examples of the above PowerShell command.