# Adding a Parameter file on VS code for Bicep template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

so Im pretty new to VS code and JSON/Bicep templates to deploy resources in Azure. Im trying to deploy a VM inside one resource group and within that RG, a vNet already created too.

the problem im having it with this:

```
param adminUsername string 


@minLength(12)
@secure()
param adminPassword string
```

When Im trying to deploy the biceps its telling me that there is any Parameter file defined so it cannot find the value for adminusername or adminpassword. I created a JSON file with the parameters:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "XXXXXXX"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "value": "XXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "dnsLabelPrefix": {
      "value": "XXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, how can I link in VS Code this Bicep template with this Parameter file so when I right click on the name it will start the deploy in my tenant?

I've read that there is a PS command to make it possible, for example:

"-TemplateParameterFile **"/home/lakshmi/module.parameters.json**""

where exactly is "/home..." folder? Is there a way to deploy the parameters+bicep template without PS?

Thanks!

I've already checked here but I find it confusing since still dont fully understand it:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76621564/passing-a-templateparameter-files-to-a-bicep-module#:~:text=To%20pass%20parameters%20in%20bicep%20files%2C%20create%20a,and%20added%20the%20parameters.json%20file%20as%20shown%20below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76621564/passing-a-templateparameter-files-to-a-bicep-module#:%7E:text=To%20pass%20parameters%20in%20bicep%20files%2C%20create%20a,and%20added%20the%20parameters.json%20file%20as%20shown%20below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of deploying your Bicep templates. You can use;

**Azure PowerShell with `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` Command**

By providing the name of the resource group, template file, and the parameter file. Example is give below;

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName 'my-resource-group' -TemplateFile .\main.bicep -TemplateParameterFile .\param.json
```

This command is run from the directory where the `main.bicep` and `param.json` files are located. This will deploy your bicep template to a Resource group. You can even deploy at the Azure Subscription level but don't worry about that at the moment.

If you want to deploy the bicep file from Visual Studio Code, you need to have couple of extensions installed. Install the following extensions

- Azure Tools - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-node-azure-pack
- Bicep - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-bicep

Once you have these 2 extensions installed, you can right-click on the bicep file and select the `Deploy Bicep file...` option. You will be asked to login to Azure and a few more inputs to gather a name for the deployment and you will be able to browse for the parameter file as well.

Follow this documentation link for step by step instructions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-vscode

Comment: Thanks a lot! You cannot imagine how much this helps. One question, when you mentioned "This command is run from the directory where the main.bicep and param.json files are located", you mean for example my C: drive? or do I need to have this files directly on my Azure root file server?

Comment: I meant where your bicep files are located. Imagine you have your bicep project in the D:\code\bicep_project folder. Then when you run this command, your PowerShell terminal should execute this from the D:\code\bicep_project folder. But you can run it from anywhere too by just providing the full path to the files. Example, D:\code\bicep_project\main.bicep.  And if you want to run it from Azure Cloud Shell, you need to copy your files to the storage account where your Cloud Shell is running. Hope this makes it clear. And I'm glad I could help out :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! So I can perfectly replace ".\main.bicep" in the code to make it look like this? "New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName 'my-resource-group' -TemplateFile D:\code\bicep_project\main.bicep -TemplateParameterFile D:\code\bicep_project\parameters.son" ? Thanks a lot for your insights, you are the best

Comment: Yep. That will work :) No problem. Happy to help.